# Get odoo 10 environment outside the http request

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

there is a need to get a 'bus.bus' model after the my module `post_load`. But I get an exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/file.py", line 19, in __call__
    self.event_bus.sendone('channel', 'message')
  File "/opt/odoo10/addons/bus/models/bus.py", line 70, in sendone
    self.sendmany([[channel, message]])
  File "/opt/odoo10/addons/bus/models/bus.py", line 54, in sendmany
    self.sudo().create(values)
  File "/opt/odoo10/odoo/models.py", line 4870, in sudo
    return self.with_env(self.env(user=user))
  File "/opt/odoo10/odoo/api.py", line 781, in __call__
    return Environment(cr, uid, context)
  File "/opt/odoo10/odoo/api.py", line 726, in __new__
    env, envs = None, cls.envs
  File "/opt/odoo10/odoo/tools/func.py", line 111, in __get__
    return self.fget.__get__(None, owner)()
  File "/opt/odoo10/odoo/api.py", line 699, in envs
    return cls._local.environments
  File "/opt/odoo10/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 72, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(name)
AttributeError: environments
```

I am try get environment like this:

```
registry = RegistryManager.get(db_name)
cursor = registry.cursor()
return Environment(cursor, None, context={})
```

So how I can get correct environment outside the http request?

Answer (score 1):

Try to get `Environment` using following.

```
from odoo import api, fields, models, _

env = api.Environment(cr, SUPERUSER_ID, {})
return env
```

Comment: Ok, but how can i get  SUPERUSER_ID?

Comment: If you don&#39;t have superuser id then pass Environment.uid

Comment: I use odoo 10 - AttributeError: type object 'Environment' has no attribute 'uid'

Comment: from odoo import SUPERUSER_ID